# Background resize

Tags: jquery

Подскажите как вместо изображения в этом [скрипте](http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/background-resize) использовать див с содержимым, или может есть что похожее, или другие способы?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо "body" пишите класс или id дива. К примеру если

```
<div class="page" style="width: 500;height:500"></div>
```

Тогда вместо "body" пишем ".page"

Comment: не вместо body, другой див. А как вместо изображения использовать див с несколькими изображениями, у меня фон составной из нескольких картинок. Надо чтобы они все изменялись как  та одна